# How to export a Chrome device profile?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I searched online and I can only find ways to export the Chrome user profile. What I want to do is to export the device profile (resolution, aspect ratio).

If yes, will it export the device frames as well? Can I use my own custom device frame?

Comment: It's in `Preferences` file in browser data directory. It's a JSON. The path is devtools.preferences.customEmulatedDeviceList.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks but I don't quite get what you said. Is this a path on the filesystem? A path in the Chrome settings? Or a path in the Chrome devTools settings? I opened the browser data directory, I see "C:\Users\<myuser>\AppData\local\Google\User data\Default\preferences". Preferences is a huge JSON file and it only contains a node called "defaultEmulatedDeviceList"

Comment: It's a json path. See if it's present in `Secure Preferences` file.